# Seeking for a method to store encrypted passwords in a human readable settings file

Tags: algorithm, encryption, methods, cross-platform, password-encryption

Attention: Please read this topic carefully: This question is **not** seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. Instead, I am seeking for a method behind existing crypto in applications. A similar previous question got locked - IMHO due to a misunderstanding.

I am looking for the **method** (and maybe an implementation hint) how others obviously safe password on user drives in a safe way. For example on Windows: You can easily store the passwords of RemoteDesktop sessions w/o the need of entering a password when re-opening the session (even after re-starting your PC). Similar is the case for SMB connections or connections to SharePoint drives. My assumption is therefore, that there must be a safe way to safe passwords. This is what I want to understand. There are (closed source) tools around that store the password in some kind of hash in a file - which only works on that particular computer. This is what I am looking for but hopefully without the need to use excessive crypto libraries.

The background is that I am developing a native cross-platform app (esp. not a web-app but C++) that requires the input of a user name and password to connect to a proxy server. For convenience I want to store this sensitive information encrypted in the settings file of the app, which has INI-File format. Therefore, the file itself shall not be encrypted.

Does someone know an easy **algorithm** or **method** to do so?

I did find and tried algorithms based on SHA hashes and so one but they all either required a master password (which doesn't help because the point is exactly not to enter a password) or they literally used tons of crypto-libraries and non-cross-platform APIs which makes it hard to come to a cross-platform implementation.

Comment: Please note that [reposting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75198697/is-there-an-easy-way-to-store-passwords-safely-in-a-human-readable-setting-file) a question because you think it was incorrectly closed is not acceptable and will probably only result in another closed question. See [how to reopen questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an easy way to store passwords safely in a human readable setting file in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75198697/is-there-an-easy-way-to-store-passwords-safely-in-a-human-readable-setting-file)

Comment: Well if it gets closed again I a in bad luck. But I re-posted because the statement clearly said: "We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations. You can edit the question or **post a new one**." (And editing lead to the original question being deleted completely.)

Comment: The link you've posted ("Is there an easy way to store passwords safely in a human readable setting file in C++") was my original question that got deleted meanwhile because its S/W related which is not accepted btw.

Answer (score 0):

All of these capabilities ultimately depend on a randomly generated master password that can only be read by a specific logged in user.

The safe way to store such a password is to encrypt it with a password that is generated from a hash of the user's login credentials.

If the user has multiple ways to log in, then a different copy of the master password must be stored for each login method, encrypted with a password generated from a hash of whatever credentials the user must supply for that particular login method.  This generally requires OS support.

Often, implementations don't explicitly bother with this, instead relying on file system security to ensure that only the desired user can read the master password.  In that case, though, you need to use disk encryption if you want to prevent the password from being accessed by super users or other means of bypassing file system security.

The disk encryption, though, will have its own master password encrypted with a login credential hash.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. So, for the example (RemoteDesktop / Shared Folder on Windows etc...) you mean saving the password is only possible because there is a master password, right? What is the master password in that case? The login credentials on Windows (to stick with that OS)? So it means the hash that is computed to store the RemoteDesktop login data is based on the password the user enters when logging in. I can understand that. But then: This saved password remains valid, if I change my login password (I just tried). This I don't understand... Any more info on that?

Comment: The master password is randomly generated and never exposed to you.  When you change your password, the master password is re-encrypted with a hash of the new credentials.  Note that this is a simplification.  For windows, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata

Comment: Al right, thank you very much for that explanation. That makes it clear. So, there is really no easy solution it seems